# mysql query using order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have field that store yes/no value that name is   `SelectionFavorite`

and I want fetch record like

first all record that contain `SelectionFavorite` value yes and other remaining records

I do some query like

```
SELECT p.Id,
       p.NameLatin,
       p.NameEnglish,
       cm.DescriptionEnglish,
       p.SelectionFavorite,
       p.SelectionGarden,
       p.SelectionPerso1,
       SelectionPerso2,
       SelectionPerso3
FROM plant p
INNER JOIN CategoryMain cm ON p.CategoryMain = cm.id
ORDER BY (p.SelectionFavorite=yes)
```

but that return only those record that have yes value.

I want to this type of result

> Id NameLatin NameEnglish DescriptionEnglish SelectionFavorite .....
>
> 1 name1 eng1 desc1 yes  yes yes no no
>
> 2 name2 eng2 desc2 yes  yes yes no no
>
> 3 name3 eng3 desc3 yes  yes yes no no
>
> 4 name4 eng4 desc4 yes  yes yes no no
>
> 5 name5 eng5 desc5 yes  yes yes no no
>
> 6 name6 eng6 desc1 no  yes yes no no
>
> 7 name7 eng7 desc2 no  yes yes no no
>
> 8 name8 eng8 desc3 no  yes yes no no
>
> 9 name9 eng9 desc4 no  yes yes no no

how to solve this query ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `order by` clause to put the "yes" values first followed by the others is:

```
ORDER BY (p.SelectionFavorite = 'yes') desc
```

Your query should not be filtering anything out, although it would be putting the non-yes values first.

Comment: this looks like it should work to me. I made a quick sample on sqlfiddle that demos what should be happening without further complications. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18fbb/4/0

Answer (score 2):

You can use a solution like this:

```
SELECT p.Id,
   p.NameLatin,
   p.NameEnglish,
   cm.DescriptionEnglish,
   p.SelectionFavorite,
   p.SelectionGarden,
   p.SelectionPerso1,
   SelectionPerso2,
   SelectionPerso3
FROM plant p
INNER JOIN CategoryMain cm ON p.CategoryMain = cm.id
ORDER BY CASE p.SelectionFavorite WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE  2 END;
```